# Slow ReactNative Android startup due to SoLoader

Tags: android, react-native

We noticed that our ReactNative app takes quite a long time to start up on Android (we tested on a physical device as well as emulators). It pauses on the splash screen.

Digging into it some more we found that "SoLoader" was taking 5-6 seconds to do it's work. We benchmarked it against other RN apps like MatterMost and StandardNotes. All those finish writing similar "SoLoader" logs in less than 200ms.

We are using React Native 0.61.5

```
08-11 07:14:54.880 23749 23749 D SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.c[root = /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
08-11 07:14:54.880 23749 23749 D SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.a[root = /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main flags = 1]
08-11 07:14:54.880 23749 23749 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.c[root = /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
08-11 07:14:54.880 23749 23749 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.a[root = /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main flags = 1]
08-11 07:14:54.977 23749 23749 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:54.977 23749 23749 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:54.996 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:54.996 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:54.998 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:54.998 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:55.009 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:55.010 23749 25778 D SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:55.141 23749 25793 D SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:55.141 23749 25793 D SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:56.758 23749 25792 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
08-11 07:14:56.758 23749 25792 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so found on /data/app/com.myapp.preprod-jMszCFAFS7K4qllOKf0dEw==/lib/arm64
08-11 07:14:59.029 23749 25838 D SoLoader: libimagepipeline.so not found on /data/data/com.myapp.preprod/lib-main
```

Where could we be going wrong and how can we make it faster?

Comment: Did you try a release build, same numbers? For us the debug build takes 4-5 seconds to be loaded by SoLoader. Release build is 200 ms. `react-native run-android --variant=release`